# How to 'grep -E' starting with whitepace until specific text encountered?

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to isolate a particular line output from a terraform command. Here's my initial output:

```
> terraform state show module.my_module.aws_cloudfront_distribution.cloudfront_resource | grep -E "id"
    hosted_zone_id                 = "..."
    id                             = "..."
    in_progress_validation_batches = 0
        target_origin_id       = "..."
        origin_id   = "..."
```

I want to zero in on the line   `id = "..."`. So I want to use a grep regex for "Start with whitespace and then id" as my test. I tried the following but to no avail:

```
... | grep -E "^\s*id"
... | grep -E "^[:blank:]*id"
```

What's the correct way?

Comment: Use `grep "^[[:blank:]]*id"`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the '-no-color' flag to prevent terraform adding color codes (that don't show up explicitly in the terminal).

```
terraform state show -no-color module.my_module.aws_cloudfront_distribution.cloudfront_resource | grep -E "^[[:blank:]]id"
```